# flycheck can't find header file even though flycheck-clang-include-path configured

Tags: flycheck, doom, c

I am using Doom Emacs as my editor for C. I'm trying to use `glib` in my C project and for that I'm including `glib.h`.
I have added the include dirs displayed by `pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0`  to `flycheck-clang-include-path`, like so:

```lisp
(add-hook! c-mode
  (setq flycheck-clang-include-path
        (list "/usr/include/glib-2.0"
              "/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include"
              "/usr/include/sysprof-4")))
```

It displays these paths in `customize` as well. However I still get the error "'glib.h' file not found" when I do `#include <glib.h>`. What am I doing wrong, how do I get flycheck to find the header?

Answer (score 0):

So, this wasn't flycheck's fault, I simply hadn't configured the LSP for this project. I did so now by generating a `compile_commands.json` file using `bear`. Everything works as expected now.